# Android Play Store - date first version submitted

Tags: android, google-play

For an app with several versions, is there a way to tell when the very first version was posted on the Google Play Store? It seems I can only find the date of the last submitted version..

(This might belong in another stack, but as a developer, I'm trying to track a Play Store timeline of various releases of one of my apps..)

Comment: sorry, but why is this downvoted? surely there are others trying to find out the dates of major releases of an app

Answer (score 4):

There's a new Google Play developer console that is supposed to show the upload date for all your apks. For our apps, though, the data seem to be missing for all but the latest.

You might have better luck looking up your app at http://www.appbrain.com and click on the "change log" tab. I believe that it shows the last 10 updates, including the date it was published. That's not the date it was uploaded, but presumably it should be close.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found it. I don't think some technique exists either for a non-uploader.
But here is what i would suggested.
Go to the **User Reviews** section for the particular application. If the application has less comments, you can determine the approximate upload date for it by viewing the oldest comment.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Bundle Explorer Selector on your left menu and check when your first version is release

[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNS4U.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an other way to find out, but you can look at you statistics and the fist point should be the very first release date:

[image]

This assuming you set the time for the graph to all.

Comment: How do you tell which release versions are in-between

Comment: Also, what if your app had 0 downloads for a long time